# Carthage: no shared framework schemes for iOS platform (for my own framework)

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I create a framework *(called ProjectOne)* built and tested it. I want to allow this framework to be used in `Carthage`. I edited my scheme and made the default `"ProjectOne"` scheme shared in `XCODE`. I did a **carthage build** and verified that the framework was build in **Carthage/Build/iOS**.

I then *push to github* and and create a release.

In another project, I'm using this framework. But, **carthage reports** *"Dependency ProjectOne has no shared framework schemes for any of the platforms: iOS"*.

I'm pretty sure I shared the scheme in ProjectOne - does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The folks at Carthage helped me discover the issue - Xcode was not adding the schemes to git. Make sure that `.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes` is added and pushed to github.

Comment: My scheme is Shared and is pushed to git, but unfortunately I still get the same error...

Comment: I'm not sure about your situation @jowie but when I hit this issue, I thought my Shared scheme was pushed to git but it wasn't. I would look at your repo and see what is in .xcodeproj.

Comment: Yeah @tng it turned out it wasn't synchronising git properly. Thanks!

Comment: I used the following command and it worked: git add -A <ProjectName>.xcodeproj/

Comment: You might want to add variouse ignores to your .gitignore file so that only .xcscheme file is shared. A tip is to copy ignores from other github projects that use carthage like Alomofire

Comment: For those not seeing the `xcshareddata` folder within the project folder, a bug in Xcode currently exists where it won't be created until you go to Edit Schemes and untick and tick "Shared" at the bottom centre. It seems to be a bug that despite it being ticked it needs a reminder to create the folder.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the issue was due the way I've included repo url in my cartfile.
I changed it from:

*github "https://...UICore.git" == 1.0.0*

to

*git "https://... UICore.git" "master"*

Comment: This was also the case for me too, making sure the format is: `git "githuburl.git" "branch"`

Answer (score 3):

Click on Manage Schemes, and then un-flag and re-flag the “Shared” voice near "YourFramework". Go to terminal and now :

```
carthage build --no-skip-current
```

Comment: Too late to answer, but I have a hope, it would help others.

Answer (score 2):

For me this was missing. I played around with scheme and pushed to GitHub `PiAnimation.xcodeproj/xcshareddata/xcschemes/PiAnimation.xcscheme`

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was new version of Xcode. I've build project in newer Xcode version, but command line tool has been set to previous. To change it you should open Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations.