# Shared scheme for Carthage

Tags: xcode, carthage

I'm trying to understand shared schemes in Xcode. For **Carthage** we should set scheme to shared option - iOS target for example. But what about test target? (iOS Tests). Should I check it as shared for **Carthage** or nor? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marking a scheme shared in Xcode makes the Scheme available outside of your user.

Effectively what it does is to move the Xcode auto-generated build scheme out of your user specific xcode folder (xcuserdata/), to the shared data folder (xcshareddata).

This is normally done if you want to build your project elsewhere and you don't want to rely on auto-generated schemes or you might have modified the auto-generated schemes (e.g. when building on a CI server).

[Carthage: no shared framework schemes for iOS platform (for my own framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054788/carthage-no-shared-framework-schemes-for-ios-platform-for-my-own-framework) shows what I mentioned as well, the scheme is moved and shared outside from your user settings.

Carthage requires this to be able to detect and build your project properly with the dependencies that you've added through Carthage.

For the second part of the question regarding test schemes: Usually you don't have extra schemes for testing and such, but rather you've configured your main scheme for the test action. If you have a separate scheme for your testing purposes (for whatever reason), they will have a build dependency on the main target/scheme that you're testing and therefore they should be linked already. You can make those schemes shared, but I doubt you'll have to.